# Link states – should keyboard focus replicate hover or active

Tags: interaction-design, accessibility, hyperlinks, hover, focus

I realise that this question may be quite specific CSS-wise, but it feels more like a UX question than a StackOverflow one.

**My question is should links have a :focus state that replicates their :hover or their :active?** I've had a read of some other sites that explain their usages (and I understand them clearly), but none seem to talk about the UX of the variants. I've also yet to find a question on here that properly addresses exactly this problem.

The way I see it is that :hover is a mouse-users indication that there is some interactivity, and that :focus is the same but for a keyboard-user; whereas :active shows that an interaction has commenced. Be that clicking, or hitting enter (although the latter would almost definitely be instantaneous so there might be no perceived :active state).

Is this the correct way to look at it, and if so is this CSS the correct way to approach it:

```
a {
  color:blue;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color:red;
}
a:focus {
  outline: dotted thin;
  // This is a slight tweak to browsers' standard :focus outline
}
a:active {
  color:green;
}
```

I'd be interested to know what people felt, and if there were any examples where people have looked at the merits of both the `:hover, :focus & :active` and the `:hover & :active, :focus` approaches, and which they found to provide a better user experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty accurate already, yes. If you have an obvious distinct `:hover` state then you should replicate that for your `:focus`.

The `:focus` is the most important one though, so make sure that exists in a clear style. Bear in mind that with the hover state, the user is (probably) visually following the cursor so is likely to already be looking at the item that has a hover state, so often designers will user a more subtle effect. However with `:focus` the user may not be looking anywhere in particular on the screen, so you need to be able to catch their eye with it. That may mean having a different `:focus` and `:hover`. But that's not really an issue, unless your styling / branding department have an issue with keyboard users being able to easily use the site!

As far as the `:active` state goes; that would depend whether you have a bespoke active state for the attrributes. *I think* that older versions of IE will only recognise the `:active` state (so if you have a `:hover` and `:focus` set up but no `:active` then it will ignore all of it and not display anything) so in those cases I would replicate the status to hover, focus AND active. But if you have a distinct `:active` state then there is no need to have the focus state match that one.

Comment: Thankfully I'm the front-end and the designer in this case so looking to set a precedent to work from.

You make a great point about the :hover being something someone is already engaging with, whereas :focus is tabbed to. Whether the :hover styling is enough will depend on the :hover styling as you say, so it may be a case of beefing it up slightly (with an outline or some other style change) to indicate where a user has tabbed to.

Comment: In my experience, branding / marketing people will be more concerned with what the hover state looks like, and have little / no concern about the focus state. My personal preference is to make the focus state *very* obvious (maybe even off-brand) to increase the visibility of it, but ensure the hover state still fits within the brand guidelines. That way you can (hopefully) keep everyone happy!

Comment: (This is for a boilerplate so ignore the colours, they're deliberately annoying to force a change when starting the project). Here's what we went with as a base – http://recordit.co/ju9OYYb3cT – it's not showing particularly well, but that's the recording I think. A little jump shows me where I am in the page, but still toying with further things, possibly making the outline more visible (the dotted is maybe a tad too subtle).